# ¿Como mostrar una variable de AngularJS a través de diferentes páginas sin que se borre?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un carrito de compras en mi página que necesito que guarde el valor del carrito y la cantidad de productos sin importar si el usuario hace click en otro link o si refresca la misma.

Mi función para el precio es la siguiente:

```
$scope.precioCarrito = function(id) {
    $scope.precio = parseInt(document.getElementById('precioCarrito').innerHTML);
    $scope.precio += parseInt($scope.productos[id].Precio);
    document.getElementById('precioCarrito').innerHTML = $scope.precio ;
};
```

Mi función para la cantidad:

```
$scope.cantidadCarrito = function() {
    $scope.cantidad++;
    document.getElementById('cantidadCarrito').innerHTML = $scope.cantidad;
};
```

Y mi index.html tiene esto:

```
        <div id="divImagenes" class="lead col-lg-4" data-ng-repeat="(id, producto) in productos">
    <div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <img data-ng-src="{{producto.Imagen}}" id="imagenDiv">
        <h6 class="list-group-item-heading" id="tituloProducto">{{producto.Nombre}}</h6>
        <span id="precio" class="list-group-item-text"><span id="signoPesos2">$</span>{{producto.Precio}}</span>
        <button id="botonAñadirCarrito" class="btn btn-info" data-ng-click="cantidadCarrito(); precioCarrito(id); agregarAlCarrito(producto)">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Y cuando se hace click en la página index.html en un botón con la leyenda AGREGAR A CARRITO se activan ambas funciones!

Hasta acá va todo bien, pero al refrescar la página o al hacer click en otro link los datos no persisten.
He intentando con el modulo de Angular ngStorage pero no tuve exito. Me gustaría hacerlo más facilmente con algo de JS nativo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar y recoger el objeto de sesión de la siguiente manera:

```
//GUARDAR OBJETO
$window.sessionStorage.setItem("item",item);
//RECOGER OBJETO
itemAux = $window.sessionStorage.getItem("item");
```

Comment: No me estaría funcionando!

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza localStorage de javascript , de esa manera podrás hacer persistentes los datos.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage